# Merge activerecord model objects, and keep only one created_at column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to do an activerecord merge on two activerecord::relation objects, but keep a specific created_at column. Here's the query:

```
Subscriber.joins(:subscriptions).merge(subscriptions)
```

Where subscriptions is another activerecord relation. I would like to use the created_at column from the subscriptions relation, but activerecord is taking the created_at column from Subscriber by default.

EDIT

The subscriptions that is being merged is this method (which returns an activerecord::relation)

```
def subscriptions
  @subscriptions ||= begin
    s = CampaignSubscription.where(:campaign_id => campaign.id).order(order_clause)
    s = s.where(:status => status)
    s = s.where(:email => email) if email.present?
    s = s.where("email ILIKE ?", "%#{q}%") if q.present?
    s
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you joining `subscriptions` and merging it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little overkill, but it should work. I haven't tested it having to then apply unions, but it works for collections.

```
Subscriber.all.select((Subscriber.column_names - ['created_at']).join(', ')).joins(:subscriptions).merge(subscriptions)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working for me. Subscriber.all is returning an array, which has a completely different select method. If I remove the all, it returns the data I'm looking for, but without a created_at column from either table.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to have an example of what you expect to get?